# SQLite and python - can't set primary keys

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite

I'm trying to create tables using python but when I inspect the data structure in SQLite, the primary keys aren't being assigned. Here's the code for one of the tables. It seems to work as intended except for the primary key part. I'm new to Python and SQLite so I'm probably missing something very obvious but can't find any answers.

```
# Create a database and connect
conn = sql.connect('Coursework.db')
c = conn.cursor()

# Create the tables from the normalised schema
c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS room_host (room_ID integer PRIMARY KEY, host_ID integer)')


c.execute("SELECT count(name) from sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='room_host'")
if c.fetchone()[0] == 1:
    c.execute("DROP TABLE room_host")
else:
    c.execute('CREATE TABLE room_host (room_ID integer PRIMARY KEY, host_ID integer)')

conn.commit()

# read data from csv

read_listings = pd.read_csv('listings.csv')
room_host = pd.DataFrame(read_listings, columns=['id', 'host_id'])
room_host.set_index('id')
room_host.to_sql("room_host", conn, if_exists='append', index=False)

c.execute("""INSERT INTO room_host (id, host_ID)
SELECT room_host.id, room_host.host_ID
FROM room_host
""")
```

Comment: Why do you create the table and then immediately delete it again?

Comment: That was how the lecturer did it when he did a live demo, although he made a few mistakes and the code didn't work. I'm learning it remotely and it's a nightmare, I don't know what I'm doing.

Comment: I see... the entire middle part with the "table exists check" does not seem to be very useful, remove it. "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS" is good enough to add a table. But it will not overwrite an existing table. So if `room_host` already exists from an earlier attempt, and it does *not* have a primary key, then this won't add one. Drop the table beforehand to ensure it's created from scratch.

Comment: I've been deleting the database each time I try just to be sure. It just seems so strange. I thought SQLite might even assign a primary key automatically if I didn't specify one but it isn't even doing that.

Comment: I'm not sure if you are looking in the right place? If the table gets created (i.e. if there is no error when you run that CREATE TABLE statement) then it *definitely* will have a primary key. So... what makes you think that it does not?

Comment: I run PRAGMA table_info(room_host) in SQLite and the pk column is empty

Comment: Remove the "IF NOT EXISTS" from the SQL. What happens?

Comment: After reading your first comment I think the first create table was redundant so I removed it completely. Should I add it back in? Everything still works except for the primary key issue.

Comment: There is only *one* way the table has no primary key, an that is when it gets created differently than you show and the `CREATE TABLE` statement you're looking at never actually runs. Run the code in my answer, stand-alone (why haven't you so far?)

Comment: Sorry should have said, I ran your code as soon as you put it up. It gives me an error 'Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 2, and there are 16 supplied.' as the table I'm reading from has more columns than the one I'm making. I don't know how to fix that.

Comment: Well... your question is based on 2 columns, not 16, and so is my answer. If your *real* CSV has 16 columns, make a two-column version just for the sake of the test. That also means that the code in your question does not really run. You haven't tested it stand-alone and you have not confirmed that it reproduces the issue you're asking about. That's ... not particularly useful, if you think about it.

Comment: In my original code I made a two column dataframe first. I'm just unsure of how to replicate that exactly using your method.

Comment: For next time: **A)** Actually run the code sample from your question. Make sure it behaves the way you say it does. **B)** Include sample input, e.g. the first few lines of the CSV you're using. This way nobody has to guess their way through your question. **C)** Focus. Pandas or the CSV file are not really your issue - the CREATE TABLE statement is, and that it doesn't seem to set up the PRIMARY KEY the way you would expect. Filling the table with data is not really related to this, so that part could have been removed.

Comment: So let's re-arrange your question. Can you come up with a bare-bones four-liner code sample that does nothing but create a table into a fresh `.db` file (import sqlite3, connect, execute, commit) and then that table does not have a primary key?

Comment: Thank you. I'm really sorry for the shambolic question. I have 2 weeks to learn this and I'm all over the place. I'm sorry again for wasting your time! Edit just saw your latest comment, I will try that

Comment: ...If you can reproduce that issue in a stand-alone code sample, show it, I'd like to see it and try it out. It's possible that I'm unaware of something in SQLite that causes that. And if a bare-bones code sample *does* do the trick, then you'll have something to do a systematic comparison to your real code from.

Comment: It's working! I followed your advice and broke it down into barebones, which solved the primary key problem, and worked in stages from that. The problem was in my dataframe to_sql, I was creating it with the same table name as the one created earlier which overrode it. Thank you so much for your kind assistance Tomalak, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Good to hear! :) I guess that takes us to **D)** Breaking things down to into bare-bones components, taking out complexity wherever you can, always is the first step in successful debugging. Too often complex setups interfere in ways that you're not anticipating.

Comment: try conn.executeScript instead of execute

Answer (score 1):

I can't reporoduce the issue with the primary key, the table is created as expected when I run that SQL statement.

Other than that, the detour through Pandas is not really necessary, the `csv` module plus `.executemany()` seems to me as a much more straight-forward way of loading data from a CSV into a table.

```
import csv
import sqlite3 as sql

conn = sql.connect('Coursework.db')

conn.executescript('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS room_host (room_ID integer PRIMARY KEY, host_ID integer)')
conn.commit()

with open('listings.csv', encoding='utf8', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    conn.executemany('INSERT INTO room_host (room_ID, host_ID) VALUES (?, ?)', reader)
    conn.commit()
```

Comment: Thanks for that. He wants us to use pandas. I don't know what's up with mine that it isn't assigning the primary key. I guess I can just create the tables directly in SQLite and explain why.

Comment: @champion_bake You can keep using Pandas if you must, that's unrelated. For the sake of an example I usually try to remove complexities, and `pandas` is *a lot* more complex than the `csv` module.